# OpenJDK JVM ignores ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a Java application run under this Java version:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)`

and I have option `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` specified on the command line. However recently I had OOME scenario where I see OOME in the logs:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`

, but the application happily continues to work, without exiting. Looks like the option is completely ignored in this scenario. I am not sure what caused the OOME yet, but why could the JVM ignore the exit option? Is there anything that can be done to ensure if OOME happens the application does exit?

Comment: Try to make a [MCVE] of this so you can verify this actually happens the way you think it happens.

Comment: @pvg unfortunately, it's very hard to do since this application is a big Java server app, and the only think I know so far is that when OOM happens, it should exit, and it doesn't. I don't think simulating it on other Java code is going to help much. I am more interested in suggestions why ExitOnOutOfMemoryError may fail to do its job.

Comment: It's going to help if you can actually reproduce non-exit on your particular JVM. That can be done with a tiny amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a [known JVM issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155004). Appears not to be fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jvmkill](https://github.com/airlift/jvmkill) JVMTI agent to terminate the JVM when unable to allocate memory or create a new native thread.